# Validating numeric sequence

Tags: java, regex

I am using Java and I need to validate a numeric sequence like this: `9999/9999`.

I tried using this regex `\\d{4}\\\\d{4}`, but I am getting `false` for `matches()`.

My code:

```
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}\\\\d{4}");

    if (!regex.matcher(mySequence).matches()) {
        System.out.println("invalid");
    } else {
        System.out.println("valid");
    }
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The regex pattern is attempting to match a backslash rather than a forward slash character. You need to use:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}/\\d{4}")
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}\\\\d{4}");
```

should be

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}/\\d{4}");
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your pattern to :

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}\\\\\\d{4}");
```

for matching `"9999\\9999"` (actual value: 9999\9999) (in java you need to escape while declaring `String`)

or if you want to match `"9999/9999"` then above solutions would work fine:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}/\\d{4}");
```